# Flex 3 MX List: need to programmatically reorder the list's item renderers

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex3

Ok, I have to use Flex 3 because I am using this in an Adobe Connect pod. I have a List component, which is capable of being reordered through drag and drop. If someone leaves the browser and comes back into the meeting room, I am trying to redisplay how they had items ordered from their drag and drop. So I need a way to reorder the list. I was looking into sort for Arrays on the dataProvider. But I have not been able to figure out the proper event to sort the list once, all of the items have the appropriate data in.

In any case, does anyone know how to tell the data of an itemRenderer to have ordered values, and then tell the list to reorder the items in the list according to the new values?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking -- are you looking for help in sorting the data or help in telling the List to redraw once the sort order has been adjusted?

Comment: Both. I actually found a solution, but was a bit of a hack. I think the way the Data_Change event got passed to my project it was interrupting my sort. I ended up putting in a flag to only have it execute my function once, and then the sort worked. I plus one'd each of the responses here, they helped a lot in leading me the right way.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible ways I used:

Keep your data in Object(map) with key:value, Object{rowIndex:rowData}

e.g. {1 : row1Data,
      2 : row2Data, ... }

Prepare the list values based on the keys and then assign it to the grid. This way, Itemrenderer will no longer need to know the "order" of the data. Their task is just to display the data.

Once user is done with drag-drop - update the map, persist it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this would work, but will take a lot more architecture to get it running. I figured out the sort on my problem, but the itemRenderers get duplicated now. I need to find a way to work with invalidateList to get the List component to either redraw itself according to the dataProvider or possibly call invalidateDisplayList neither one right now is doing anything to my UI though.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an ArrayCollection, you can apply a sort, and then call arrayCollection.refersh() to refresh the collections with the sort, which will then update the list display

Comment: Yes my list display is now updating, but I have custom itemRenderers that are duplicating after the sort is finished. Trying to look into invalidateList or invalidateDisplayList to redraw the component.